# how can we make a div visible after 10 mins in playing a video

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

I have a video streaming from amazon s3. I want to make a div visible after 10 mins after the video has started. I know i can write a code to make the div visible after 10 mins. But my question is is it possible to make the div visible at the 10th min of the video.

For eg. If someone is viewing the video and clicks on video control bar to fast forward to the 9.56 min of the video, i would like to view the div on the 10 min of the video rather than after 10 mins of the video started playing.

I am not sure if its possible at all. Any ideas or pointers would be helpful

Thanks

Prady

Comment: The solution depends on video player. Which one are you using to play the video?

Comment: Read the amazon player API documentation. For example, VIMEO has its own javascript framework, though it is very complicated to understand. Maybe amazon has something too.

Comment: @WTK i am using jwplayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup the javascript callback on [`onTime`](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference#Events) event provided by jwplayer.

```
jwplayer("container").onTime(function(event) {
    // event.position contains playback position in seconds so to detect we're after
    // 10 min point we check if position is larger than 10 * 60 = 600 seconds.
    if (event.position > 600) {
        alert("we're after 10 minutes of video!");
    }
});
```

Note: in above example "container" is a div with id attribute equal to "container" - it's the div your jqplaer gets into.